# In JQGrid - How to set value in a field in edit dialog programmatically

Tags: jqgrid

I am using JQGrid with Spring + Hibernate in my web application. I have created a functionality wherein JQGrid opens an edit dialog for editing a selected row, wherein I have created a custom button. When a user clicks this custom button, a dialog box opens and user selects a row from this dialog. When user clicks 'Ok' control moves back to JQGrid Edit dialog.
I just want the selected value from the dialog for a field to be copied in the field in JQgrid edit dialog. I am able to get the value from the dialog in a global javascript variable, but not able to set it in the JQGrid edit dialog field. Please help me doing this.

Relevent code from my javascript file is pasted below:

```
     function JQDialog(title, contentUrl, params) {
        var dialog1 = $("#codesdlg").dialog(
        {
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            title: title,
            zIndex: 1000,
            close: function (e, ui) { dialog1.remove(); },
            buttons: { "Ok": function () 
                {
                    alert("Selected A/c Code: " + selAccode + ' - '+selAcDescr); 
                    $('#TblGrid_list').$('#tr_acccode').val(selAccode);
                    dialog1.dialog("close"); } 
            }
        });

        dialog1.load(contentUrl, function () {
             dialog1.dialog('open');
        });

//                dialog1.load(contentUrl).dialog('open');

    };


     $("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:true,refresh:false}, 
             { 
               recreateForm: true, dataheight: 375, width: 400, height: 450, zIndex:75,
               beforeShowForm: function(form) {$('#tr_ccode',form).hide();

               $('<a href="#">Select<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-search"></span></a>')
                .click(function(rowid, iRow, iCol, cellValue, e) {
                    JQDialog("Test Dialog","../acctmstmgmt/opendlg",rowid);
//                    var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(rowid); 
//                    rowData.acccode = selAccode;
//                    $('#list').jqGrid('setRowData', rowid, rowData);
//                    $("#list").jqGrid("setCell", rowid, "acccode", selAccode);
//                    alert(selAccode);
//                    $('#trv_acccode').val(selAccode);
//                    window.open("../acctmstmgmt/opendlg", 'Dialog', 'width=700,height=300', top=500, left=500 );


                }).addClass("fm-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all fm-button-icon-left")
                  .appendTo("#tr_acccode"); 

               }
             },
             { 
              recreateForm: true, dataheight: 375, width: 400, height: 450, zIndex:75,
              beforeShowForm: function(form) {$('#tr_ccode',form).show();

                $('<a href="#">Select<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-search"></span></a>')
                .click(function() {
                    alert('Clicked');
                }).addClass("fm-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all fm-button-icon-left")
                  .appendTo("#tr_acccode"); 

              }
             },
             {
             },
             {  // search
                sopt:['cn', 'eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt', 'bw', 'ew'],
                closeOnEscape: true,
                multipleSearch: true,
                closeAfterSearch: true
            });
 });

$.jgrid.edit = {
     addCaption: "Add Codes Master",
     editCaption: "Edit Codes Master",
     bSubmit: "Submit",
     bCancel: "Cancel",
     bClose: "Close",
     bYes : "Yes",
     bNo : "No",
     bExit : "Cancel",
     closeAfterAdd:true,
     closeAfterEdit:true,
     reloadAfterSubmit:true,
     modal:true,
     msg: {
             required: "is mandatory or required",
             number: "is a number field. Enter a valid number",
             minValue: "should not be less than ",
             maxValue: "should not be more than "
             },
    errorTextFormat: function (response) {
         if (response.status !== 200) {
             return '<div style="overflow-y: scroll;">'+
                "Error encountered while processing. Please check the accuracy of data entered.-" + response.status + " "+response.responseText
                + '</div>';
         }
     },
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue with following code

simply placed following code in the "Ok" button function

$('#acccode').val(selAccode);

here acccode is colModel field and selAcccode is global javascript variable from where value is placed in the edit form field.